# How does the tankless water heater igniter with a single wire generate a spark?

Tags: ac

I have a Takagi ATO 310U tankless water heater which is currently not firing up. Just trying to understand how the igniter with a single wire can generate a spark.

Answer (score 3):

Ground (the metal parts of the appliance) is typically the return path for the ignitor spark. [Here](https://www.acfgreenhouses.com/sterling-gg-spark-ignitor) is one type of ignitor:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The chassis is the return path for the ignition current.

[image]